# what's $\int \sin (e^x)\ dx$ ??

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I was working on a physics problem and I faced this integral:
$$\int \sin(e^x) \, dx =$$

I tried to solve it but I could not.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin\big(e^x\big)~dx~=~\dfrac\pi2~.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using taylor, $$\int \sin(e^x)dx=-\int\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-e^x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-e^x)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)(2k+1)!}.$$

Converges for all $x$.

Comment: How do you get the last equality?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD, integrating term to term.

Comment: That's how I would have proceeded!  +1

Answer (score 10):

$$ \int\sin{e^x}dx = \int{\frac{\sin{e^x}}{e^x}e^xdx} = \int{\frac{\sin t}{t}dt} = Si(t) + C = Si(e^x) + C$$

Where $Si(x)$ - sine integral and it can not be expressed in terms of elementary functions. [See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

Answer (score 1):

According to Wolfram this integral is $Si(\exp(x))$ ([The sine integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html))

Answer (score 0):

It has [no explicit solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20sin%28e%5Ex%29dx), you can express the integral in terms of the [SI function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html) or compute it numerically if it appears as a definite integral.